# Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider.when handler result ignored by $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-rewriting, angular-ui-router

I added a `when()` method to set/validate a route prefix, which looks something like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when(/[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}/, [
  '$match','myValidatorSrv',
  function($match, myValidatorSrv) {
    if ( myValidatorSrv.validate($match[0]) ) return true;
    // …
    return $match.input.replace($match[0],'en-us');
  }
]);
$urlRouterProvider.when(/(?![a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})/, [
  '$match','myValidatorSrv',
  function($match, myValidatorSrv) {
    // …
    return $match.input.replace('/', '/en-us/');
  }
]);
```

The re-writing happens as I expect, and I get `/en-us/home` (GET `/home`).

My states are set up like so:

```
$stateProvider
.state('base', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/{locale}'
})
.state('base.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'home@': {
            templateUrl: '/partials/home.html'
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, with the `when()`s in place, the states no-longer match (the view does not get loaded); even when I manually go to `/en-us/home`, the state still does not get triggered.

Do I need to do something special to get $state to re-evaluate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O2MdURp9zgtP4mdHzIZp?p=preview)

This would be the adjusted `.when()`

```
$urlRouterProvider.when(/[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}/,
  ['$match', function($match) {

    var supported = ['cs-cz', 'en-us', 'en-gb'];  
    var isSupported = supported.indexOf($match[0]) >= 0 ;
    if(isSupported){
      return false;
    }
    return $match.input.replace($match[0], 'en-us');
  }
]);
$urlRouterProvider.when(/^(.(?![a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}))/,
  ['$match', function($match) 
  {
    return $match.input.replace('/', '/en-us/');
   }
]);
```

That all is related to the:

#### [$urlRouterProvider - `when()` for redirection](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#when-for-redirection)

small cite:

> `handler` as Function
>
> If the handler is a function, it is injectable. It gets invoked if $location matches. You have the option of inject the match object as $match
>
> The handler can return:
>
> - **falsy** to indicate that the rule didn't match after all, then $urlRouter will continue trying to find another one that matches.
> - a **String**, which is treated as a redirect and passed to $location.url()
> - **nothing** or any **truthy** value tells $urlRouter that the url was handled

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O2MdURp9zgtP4mdHzIZp?p=preview)

Comment: OMG, I should've been using `return false` instead of `return true` ^^, Thanks!