# AngularJS Ui Router match multiple routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to match multiple state within ui-router ?
I have a number of routes which share the same template and controllers

```
.state('someState', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'someContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates.html",
          controller: 'SomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })


.state('someOtherState', {
      url: "/other",
      views: {
        'someContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates.html",
          controller: 'SomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

Eg something like :

```
.state('someState', {
      url: ["/home", "/other" ],
      views: { ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest to observe the [`.when()` for redirection](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#when-for-redirection). It will work for basic stuff.... It could be not only simple string-url to string-url but even much more complex, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172461/angular-ui-router-urlrouterprovider-when-handler-result-ignored-by-state)